# Firebase C++ SDK and Google Auth

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-authentication

How can one use Firebase Authentication to allow users to authenticate with a Google account via the C++ SDK (using it in Cocos2d-x).

I’m confused as to whether I would need to build a special Google auth GUI or if the SDK requires/contains a standardized GUI (or, in the case of Cocos2d-x, a Scene) that should be used.

Either way, I am unsure how to do it.  Does anyone know how to proceed?  The SDK example code shows how to authenticate via Email/Password but not via a Google Account.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is complicated, but not because of Firebase.

Basically, if you want to use a Federated Logon, such as [Facebook](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/cpp/facebook-login), [Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/cpp/google-signin), [Twitter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/cpp/twitter-login), then you will need to use their UI SDK built for whichever platform you are using.  When you successfully login with one of these services, you will construct a Credential with the `token` that is returned from one of these services.

After you login with this credential, the Firebase Auth service will associate any account data with this federated logon.  If you were previously using an anonymous login, then the account should be upgraded.  If you have already logged in with another credential (email, phone number, alternative federeated logon) then you will need to do some logic to check if you need to merge or switch.

Firebase Auth can outlive the Federated Token.  For example, the Facebook Login token expires or is revoked, your Firebase Auth backend might remain signed in.  Vice versa your Facebook token might not expire, but your Firebase Auth might have been signed out.  You will need to manage these states.

---

Here's an example.  We want to use Facebook Login as our federated logon provider.  We link the Facebook Login SDK for our platform as described in the [Facebook Developer docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/).

When we want to ask for Facebook login credentials, we use the FBSDKLoginManager .loginwithReadPermissions() to launch the login flow.  This typically consists of launching either the Facebook App to confirm permissions for your app or the website (make sure you implement deep links properly as described in the Facebook documentation).

Eventually, the login will succeed or fail.

If it succeeds, Facebook will hand you a token which you can grab from `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString`.  This is what you would send to `firebase::auth::FacebookAuthProvider::GetCredential`

---

All of this is ASync and done on separate threads.  You should use a concurrent queue to funnel these events to your main thread.

It is possible to use your own server and signup form, in which case you would build your own UI in game and then make secure server calls to your backend.  There's a flow for getting a text message to validate a user, not something I would do for a game.

Comment: I cannot find how to instantiate the Google UI for authentication from within the C++ SDK.  for Facebook, you mentioned FBSDKLoginManager .loginwithReadPermissions().  Is there something similar for Google auth?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/  (There are Android SDKs too)

Comment: Also, you aren't initiating the Google, Twitter, Facebook,etc.. Login UI from C++ SDK, you are doing it from that specific SDK.  If you are using Cocos2d-X, then there should be plugins or examples how to integrate these SDKs in their forums.